# Сортировка в Oracle DB

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, oracle, oracle12c

Каким образом можно отсортировать запрос в специфичном порядке, например есть ID 10, 20, 50. Я хочу отсортироваться именно в порядке 10, 50, 20. Покопался в интернете но ответ так и не смог найти...

```
SELECT
a.department_id, 
b.department_name,
a.job_id
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES a 
LEFT JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS b
ON a.department_id = b.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = 10

UNION ALL

SELECT
a.department_id, 
b.department_name,
a.job_id
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES a 
LEFT JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS b
ON a.department_id = b.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = 50


UNION ALL

SELECT
a.department_id, 
b.department_name,
a.job_id
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES a 
LEFT JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS b
ON a.department_id = b.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = 20;
```

Comment: вот в данном конкретном случае с union, достаточно добавить в запросы select еще одно поле с порядковым номером запроса. т.е. в первом select добавляете `1 as ord`, во втором на этом месте 2 и т.д. и в конце спокойно пишите `order by ord`

Comment: Другое дело что тут union совершенно не нужен и можно обойтись одним блоком с `a.department_id in(10, 50, 20)`, а тогда можно сделать скажем `order by decode(department_id, 10, 1, 50, 2, 20, 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например можно сделать это так:

```
SELECT a.department_id, b.department_name, a.job_id
  FROM HR.EMPLOYEES a 
  LEFT JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS b
    ON a.department_id = b.department_id
 WHERE a.department_id IN(10, 50, 20)
 ORDER BY decode(department_id, 10, 1, 50, 2, 20, 3)
```

Фактически для order заменяем department_id на порядковый номер, нужный для сортировки.

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить колонку для сортировки с `CASE` оператором:

```
select a.department_id, b.department_name, a.job_id,
    case a.department_id 
    when 10 then 1 
    when 50 then 2 
    when 20 then 3 end sort
from hr.employees a 
left join hr.departments b ON a.department_id = b.department_id
where a.department_id in (10, 50, 20)
order by sort
```

Если это условие для сортировки используется часто, то обычно такую колонку добавляют невидимой в таблицу:

```
alter table hr.departments add (sort int invisible as (
    case department_id 
    when 10 then 1 
    when 50 then 2 
    when 20 then 3 end));
```